# Will parent bean be created by Spring in this case

Tags: java, spring

Have a doubt, in the below example will spring create a bean for parent class(Address).  If yes how can we evidence it, new to Spring :)  apologies if i dont make sense.

```java
public class Address {
    private String address = "XXX,YYYYY";
    public  Address(){
        System.out.println(" Inside Address Constructor ");
    }
    public String toString(){
        return address ;
    }
    public void printAllDetails(){
        System.out.println( " Printing all the details of address .....");
    }
}

public class OfficeAddress  extends Address{
    public  OfficeAddress(){
        System.out.println(" Inside OfficeAddress Constructor ");
    }
    public void printAllDetails(){
        System.out.println( " Printing all the details of office address .....");
    }
}

public class TestClasspathApplicationContext {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpathapplicationcontext.xml");

        // Will Address bean be created and maintained by Spring - ?
        Address offaddress = context.getBean("officeaddress", OfficeAddress.class);
        offaddress.printAllDetails();
    }
}
```

**Spring configuration file**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans...>
      <bean id="officeaddress" 
       class="com.springprct.ioc.applicationcontext.classpathsystem.OfficeAddress"/>
    </beans>
```

Thanks

Comment: Could I clear your doubt?

Comment: Thanks for you response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **No**. Spring will create only those custom beans which are inside the `<bean>` tag in your `applicationContext.xml` or annotated with `@Bean` or classes annotated with Spring annotations like @Configuration, @Component, @Service, etc etc

If you want to verify what all beans Spring has created , just do this:

```
String[] beans = context.getBeanDefinitionNames();
for(String bean:beans){
     System.out.println("Bean name: " + bean);
     Object object = appContext.getBean(bean);
     System.out.println( "Bean object:" + object);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**No**, it will not. Spring Container will register 3 kind of bean definitions:

1. Classes, which are manually configured as `<bean>` elements in your contextConfiguration.xml (*when you use classpath xml as your container configuration file*);
2. Classes, which are annotated by `@Component` and any of its descendants (*when you either use AnnotationConfig container, enable ComponentScan in your xml or @Configuration class*);
3. Returned objects from `@Bean` methods, as long as those methods belong to `@Configuration` class.

Comment: Thanks for you response